# Search different date format in elastic search

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I've indexed a date column from my mysql database with the following configuration

```
                    mappings:
                    first_name: { boost: 5 , type: string, index: not_analyzed }
                    last_name: { boost: 5, type: string, index: not_analyzed}
                    id:
                        type: integer
                    date_create:
                        type: date
                        format: YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

How can I query elastic search using different date formats?
e.g. any items that have 2015-10-01 as index should be searchable when I search for 'October 1' or 'Oct 1'

Is there a way to do it in elasticsearch or do I have to format the date before passing it to the finder?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tool to convert the user input into a full Date/DateTime/DateTimeOffset object.

In javascript [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) would be a great choice.

In C# DateTimeOffset.TryParse() is your friend.

Whatever language you're using I'm sure there is a built in date conversion library.

Comment: ah, so the only solution is setting it to a predefined format before passing it to elasticsearch?

Comment: I think that it is the best solution. Separate your concerns. Let ES do what it does best and don't burden it with user input validation. That should be done more on the UI layer not the repo/database layer.